# Search in array of char* in c

Tags: c, optimization

I am trying to work out what is wrong with the process of scanning the char* star value.

```
struct Property  {
unsigned int shift;
int mask;
char * str[4];
 } 
human [] = {
{0, 1, {"fe", "ma"}},
{1, 1, {"du", "cl"}},
{2, 1, {"nh", "ha"}},
{3, 1, {"sk", "tr"}},
{4, 3, {"bn", "rd", "bw", "bk"}},
{6, 3, {"bu", "ge", "gy", "da"}},
};

int find(char*  w){
int i;
int j;
for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(human)/ sizeof(struct Property)); i++){
    for (j = 0; j < 4 ; j++){
            if (human[i].str[j] == w)
                return i;
    }
}
}


int main(){

char* w ;
scanf("%s", w);
int k = find(w);
printf("k is %d", k);
return 0;
}
```

Clion compiler says that 'pointer parameter w can be pointer to const'. So in my main() I tried to use my function scanning w as array or char*.

Upd with suggestions.

```
struct Property {
unsigned int shift;
int mask;
char * st[4];
} human [] = {
    {0, 1, {"fe", "ma"}},
    {1, 1, {"du", "cl"}},
    {2, 1, {"nh", "ha"}},
    {3, 1, {"sk", "tr"}},
    {4, 3, {"bn", "rd", "bw", "bk"}},
    {6, 3, {"bu", "ge", "gy", "da"}},
};

int find(char*  w)
{
int i;
int j;
for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(human)/ sizeof(struct Property)); i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 4 ; j++)
    {
            if ((strcmp(human[i].st[j], w)) == 0)
                return i;
            else
                continue;
    }
}
return -1;
}


int main()
{

char* w = malloc(sizeof(char*));
scanf("%99s", w);
int k = find(w);
if (k != -1 )
    printf("k is %d", k);
if (k == -1) { printf("%s","Error");}
return 0;
}
```

Still no output.I truly believe, that something is still wrong

Comment: `strcmp(human[i].str[j] , w)`

Comment: scanf - you didn't allocate mem

Comment: you should not use scanf("%s",w) with w a unitialized pointer, w should be an array, or at least point to some legal memory

Comment: @coderredoc you mean to change the last if statement in function ?

Comment: compiler probably suggests `int find(const char*  w)` because `w` doesn't change in the function. That's a nice suggestion.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to compare strings with ==, also, you're not accounting for the fact that some rows have 4 strings and some have fewer.

Answer (score 4):

There are couple of problems -

- Allocate memory to `w`. Other wise passing an uninitialized pointer to `scanf` is Undefined behavior. (You can allocate the memory dynamically too)

  ```
  char w[100];
  if( scanf("%99s",w) != 1 ){
     /* Handle error */
  }
  ```
- Comparing two strings can be done using `strcmp`. Using `==` operator is not the correct way.

  ```
  if ( strcmp(human[i].str[j], w) == 0 )
  ```
- Also you should always return something from the function. It is supposed to return something even if nothing matches. But you didn't follow that contract. Compiler complained.

  ```
  for(..){
    ...
  }
  return -1; /* denoting invalid index - search failed*/
  ```
- You can easily make the argument passed as `const char *` because you are not changing it's value (the content of the string).

Comment: Firstly, is it possible to use just char * w in main? I do not really got you, in the moment when we allocate the memory for w. I am supposed just to write the     char* w[1] ;
    w[0] = malloc(sizeof(char*)); And then, after     scanf("%s", w[0])        send it to a function?Like some int = find(w[0]). Secondly, when I included strcmp in my function it seems not to work. Like it doesn't have an output.

Comment: And how to deal with the lack of output from the function. I now have      if ((strcmp(human[i].str[j], w)) == 0) returns i , and else it continues the cycle. Also added return 0 in the very end of the function. But still, no output. Had an idea just to switch the function to void type , and make it print, but it still didn't seem to work.Sorry,for being kind of annoying, as I want to understand the think.

Comment: @jackjones.: Don't guess...now you have some other problem. I mentioned to `return -1` and then check it in main. `if (retvalue == -1) { printf("%s","Error");`

Comment: I will appreciate , if you can help me to point out the remaining mistakes.